# Where is my wrong about deducing Lorentz transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I want to show the time dilation of Lorentz transformations by Michelson-Morley experiment (the second picture below). But I fail and can't find the wrong. Below is how I derived it:

Assuming the time from $B$ to $C'$ is  $t$, then
$$
(ct)^2=L^2+(ut)^2  \tag{1}
$$
where $c$ is velocity of light. Therefore, I have
$$
t=\frac{L/c}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}  \tag{2}
$$
On the other hand, for the people in $(x',y',z',t')$, there should be
$$
t'= L/c ~~~~\text{namely}~~~  L=ct'   \tag{3}
$$
(2) and (3) imply
$$
t'=t\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}  \tag{4}
$$
But obviously, (4) is not the right time dilation, where is the wrong ?

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Your newest version of this question is just a identification mistake. The person in which the apparatus is not moving, is the one measuring the proper time. That means $c\tau=ct^\prime=L$ and $ct=\frac L{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}=\frac{c\tau}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}$ and so you already have time dilation obtained correctly. You should always consider for something to be purely measuring time at one place or purely measuring length at one time, so you should have $2L$ rather than $L$.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent   So, $\tau=t\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$ is right ?

Comment: Correct; This says time dilation.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent  But in Lorentz  transformations, it should be $\tau=\frac{t-ux/c^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}$. They are different.

Comment: Again, you are making a huge mistake. Time dilation says $t=\frac\tau{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}$. Time dilation is an _ingredient_ that you need to get to Lorentz transformation equations. If you only know time dilation, you do not know what Lorentz transforms are. You have to put in new physics ideas and arguments, to get Lorentz transformations. More ingredients than just time dilation.

Answer (score 1):

> Since Feynman omit the process of time of Lorentz transformation,

What do you even mean? "process of time"?

---

Also, it is insane for you to be considering the stuff that Feynman explicitly considered, in the ordering that he considers, and hope to extract more than what it says. In particular, Feynman states without proof nor deduction in Vol. 1 Chapter 15 Section 2 the Lorentz transformations. The next section, section 3, he covers the Michelson-Morley experiment. This is very smart, because in one experiment, he extracts, in section 3, length contraction, and in section 4, time dilation. He even gives you, in section 5, a way to deduce the Lorentz transformation of length from both of them.

In fact, you are using his pictures, so I do not know what you mean when you say you are supplementing.

That is, already in your Equation (1) and the line before that, you should have noted that $t_1$ and $t_2$ refer to the contracted length $L^\prime$, and thus should never have been written down as $L$; Feynman was trying to point out the wrong assumption in non-relativistic viewpoints, which is why he initially used $L$ for that. He quickly fixed that later on.

Also, it is usual in treatments of SR to first derive time dilation and Lorentz contraction, before assembling them to deduce the full Lorentz transformations. This requires argumentation, which is not fully presented in Feynman lectures. In section 5, he gives you the argument to get from them to one of the 4 Lorentz transformation equations. Two more of these equations are trivial to obtain. The last equation is homework for you, and it is not exactly an easy argument. You have to think very carefully to get that argument correct.

Comment: The process of time means the process of 4th equality of 3th picture ,namely time dilation (I'm not a physics major, and I'm using the Chinese version of the book, and I didn't know the word until I saw you say it), since it is the  time part of Lorentz transformation.  I say supplement mean that I want to show the 4th equality of 3th picture. The last equality in my problem is what I derive. I know it is wrong. But I don't know where is the wrong. So, I ask this problem. I'll think about it, or look it up. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the time part of the Lorentz transformation is much better at telling us what your problem is. 你的問題是邏輯上就出現問題了。你要的話是應該理解一下第 15 章第 5 節他是怎麼以新的物理思維把第三第四節的物理融合成 space part of Lorentz transformation, 才有機會自己生成 time part of Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to take a closer look at verse 5 of chapter 15, it's quite short, so I just glanced at it at first. Thnaks.

Comment: Section 5, not verse. 不是語句，是章節。尤其不是聖經條文。

Comment: 嗯，我的英语和你的中文旗鼓相当 :-)

Comment: err，你說甚麼，我是雙母語耶

Comment: I said your Chinese doesn't seem to be much better than my English.  I didn't know you were a dual speaker. I thought you translated it with software.

Comment: 如果是軟體翻譯的話也不會選擇用繁體字吧

Comment: 那倒也是，只是你前面有句子看起来有点怪。比如“你要的話是應該理解一下第 15 章”， 你是不是打错字了？ 我重新编辑过我那个问题，我另外找了个途径计算出了正确的 time dilation， 但是我问题里面这个思路我还是没找到错误在哪。

Comment: 『你要的話，是應該理解一下第 15 章第 5 節』，沒打錯，少了個逗號而已。通常正確的邏輯是先找時間膨脹，再找長度收縮，才打算合成 Lorentz transformations. Feynman 反而先得到長度收縮也可以。Lorentz transformations 屬於時空座標轉換，不只是時間膨脹和長度收縮，是須要多加物理思維才能得到的。15 章 5 節就是用理由解釋為甚麼可以又有 x 又有 t 而只有 $x^\prime$ 才是座標轉換應該有的樣子。所以才說你的邏輯一開始就錯了。建議你當作 15 章 2 節不存在。

Comment: But to be frank, while Feynman is very good at teaching, but on Special Theory of Relativity he is pretty much too smart and basically impossible to understand. You will be better off if you read a standard treatment of the subject, especially something that uses Minkowski diagrams.

Comment: 我买了本狭义相对论（刘辽、费保俊，张允中三个人写的），应该明天就到了，我到时候再仔细看看。谢谢拉。